# Getting vertex coordinates from \feynmandiagram

Tags: coordinates, feynman, tikz-feynman

It is handy to have the automated vertex placement at `\feynmandiagram` from the `tikz-feynman` package.

Is it possible to retrieve vertex coordinates from the `\feynmandiagram` block? 
In the following example

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \feynmandiagram[horizontal=v0 to v1]{
    v0 -- [boson] v1,
    v20 -- [fermion] v1,
    v1 -- [fermion] v21,
  };
  draw[->] (v20) -- (v21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to do an additional operation using the vertex coordinates:

```
  draw[->] (v20) -- (v21);
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates are accessible in the environment form:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}[horizontal=v0 to v1]
    \diagram {
      v0 -- [boson] v1,
      v20 -- [fermion] v1,
      v1 -- [fermion] v21,
    };
    \draw[red, ->] (v20) -- (v21);
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]